Shortcuts not working in Spyder notebook, why?
I just installed the notebook extension in spyder. I have used it for months and never had problems. Now, all of a sudden, the Jupyter notebook shortcuts (e.g., dd for deleting a cell) do not work anymore, despite being explicitly shown as available shortcuts.
How do I activate the typical Jupyter Notebook shortcuts in Spyder notebooks?
